# Temporary files in C++. tmpnam alternatives

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get a temporary filename so I can use it in an argument to a child process.  The child process will output to that file, then I'll open the file, read the contents, and delete the file.

[std::tmpnam](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpnam) seems perfect for this.

Here is a trivial example of it being used:

```
std::string file = std::tmpnam(nullptr);

boost::process::child c(boost::process::search_path("tar"), { "-czf", file, ... } );
c.wait();

SendArchive(file); // opens, reads, and closes file

std::filesystem::remove(file);
```

However `g++` issues a warning:

> warning: the use of 'tmpnam' is dangerous, better use 'mkstemp'

---

What can I use as an alternative?

- `mkstemp` is posix-specific
- [`std::tempfile`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpfile) only returns a file-descriptor.  I can't pass that to `tar`, and prefer to not manually read `/proc/self/fd/` to get the name.  If there is a platform-independent method to convert the file-descriptor into a string, I'd be happy to do that.
- [`boost::unique_path`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#unique_path) is possible, but then I'm starting to mix std::filesystem and boost::filesystem which I'm worried I'll regret later.
- I'm tempted to use [`std::filesystem::temp_directory_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/temp_directory_path) and then add my own randomly generated characters to it.

Comment: Did the warning explain **why** someone felt that you need to be warned about this function? Did you [read the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpnam) to see why it might be considered "dangerous"?

Comment: I read the documentation (I liked to the same page). It says "not required to be thread safe", and suggests it's possible another process might think of the same name. It says `std::tempfile` and `mkstemp` are alternatives which I've already talked about here.

Comment: temp_directory_path() will return "/tmp", not a new unique direcrory.

Comment: You probably want to communicate via a pipe instead.

Comment: Is the child process an external program, or just an internal `fork()`? If the latter, where you control the interface, you might be better off with shared memory, or passing an open file descriptor shared between child and parent.

Comment: The child process is an external program (otherwise, I would have used a better interface).

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to avoid POSIX? It's normally a plus.

Comment: If you can pass parameters to the child process, you can consider shared memory, passing a shared memory key for access.